# Error while compiling shader in GLSL

Tags: glsl

Apart from code, I'd like to know what this error is about:

```
two vertex attribute variables (named a and n) were assigned to the same generic vertex attribute
```

which I came across while compiling my vertex shader in GLSL (an experiment for transform feedback) with Nsight on Ubuntu. I mean, which are all the possible causes of this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are binding two different vertex attributes to the same location in your OpenGL code.

For example, when you bind attributes you usually do this:

```
glBindAttribLocation(program, 0, "AttributeName");
```

What you must be doing is using the same index for both attributes:

```
glBindAttribLocation(program, 0, "AttributeNameOne");
glBindAttribLocation(program, 0, "AttributeNameTwo");
```

Generate another generic vertex attribute location and this should disappear.
You can use whatever non-negative numbers you like (in a small range).

Also keep in mind that glBindAttribLocation has to be called before linking the program.